# Generic category of PBT thermoplastic

Tags: materials, plastic, chemistry

I'm an EE, but I'm working on a project at work where I need to venture into materials science & chemistry.

My question is, does thermoplastic, Polybutylene terephthalate (PBT), fall into any of these material categories?

[image]

Comment: Not an expert, but, as far as I can see, No.
Why? A bit more context might help users give a more helpful answer.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift.  Your feedback is noted, but I disagree.  In this case context would just muddy up what should be a relatively straightforward answer to a relatively straightforward question.

Comment: Why is beryllium oxide even on the list? Or nylon or polycarbonate or formaldehyde? I'm an EE and even I know these are distinct materials, not categories of materials.

Answer (score 1):

No . A more common polymer is polyethylene terepthalate  ( PET) from which many bottles are made . I guess they would be the same group if it has a name.

Comment: Tetrapthalates!

Comment: Check the internet.